# How to set hinge friction?

Tags: constraints

I am using a hinge in my animation. The problem is that the friction rapidly limits the movements. Is there a way to tune it?

Comment: A hinge has no friction to take away.  Instead, reduce damping on the rigid body that is constrained, in properties/physics/rigid body/dynamics.

Comment: @Nathan you could post that as an answer also, so why didn't you?

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Because it's short and would get deleted.

Comment: @Nathan I guess you're probably right, but if it solves the question, I don't see any reason for it to get deleted...

Comment: @YousufChaudhry: well, you are pretty new here and i can tell you: Nathan is absolutely right. I made this experience 100x times and more...maybe i have the record of deleted answers on this site....

Comment: Great pity Nathan can't get an upvote for this perfectly correct answer. Thanks Nathan!